# Brackets around rep in reputation summary

Tags: support

If I go to my rep summary at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, I can see this for today:

```
 2  74322480 [10]
 1  74322522 [15]
 1  74317432 [15]
 2  74317432 [0]
```

I know `[0]` probably means an upvote that didn't count (because I hit the upvote cap), but what does `[15]` mean? Above the previous entries were these, which have parentheses instead of brackets:

```
 1  74318124 (15)
 2  74318124 (10)
 2  74319366 (10)
 1  74319366 (15)
```

What's the difference between `(15)` and `[15]`?

Comment: the only thing that can give you 15 rep is an accept.

Comment: @KevinB Yea, but why is it in brackets `[15]` and not like the other ones which are in parentheses `(15)`?

Comment: i see. In my own rep history,  only see square brackets on days where i reached rep cap

Answer (score 6):

As listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43005/1190884), the third number is the amount of rep gained or lost. When you reach the rep cap, the number is wrapped in brackets instead of parentheses. Here's an example from my summary:

```
 2  74310771 (10) 1
 1  74308031 (15)
 2  74308031 (10) 2
 1  74310771 (15)
 1  74283820 (15)
 2  74308111 (10) 3
 1  74309884 (15)
 2  74310771 (10) 4 
 2  74312017 (10) 5
 2  71339428 (10) 6
 2  74312277 (10) 7
 2  74312251 (10) 8
 1  74312251 (15)
 1  74312186 (15)
 2  74308372 (10) 9
 1  74308372 (15)
 1  74306234 (15)
 2  74306234 (10) 10
 2  74318154 (10) 11
 1  74318124 (15)
 2  74318124 (10) 12
 2  74319366 (10) 13
 1  74319366 (15)
 2  74319366 (10) 14
 2  74318154 (10) 15
 2  74321538 (10) 16
 2  74322480 (10) 17
 2  74322480 (10) 18
 2  74322522 (10) 19
 2  74322480 [10] 20 *reached cap*
 1  74322522 [15]
 1  74317432 [15]
 2  74317432 [0]
```